# context files in deployment in azure

Tags: eclipse, azure

I have 3 files in my grails application : appli.war, config.groovy and contextAppli.xml

the contextAppli.xml code is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Context 
    path="." 
    docBase="appli.war"
  reloadable="false">

  <Parameter
    name="configLocation"
    override="false"
    value="file:c:/tomcat/config.groovy"/>


</Context>
```

But when I do an azure deployment project with my war in eclipse, I can't specifie the location of config.groovy and contextAppli.xml.
So my deployment doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should define a startup task using PowerShell commands to copy the files where you need them when the role is deployed.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg456327.aspx